# Why does enumerable: false not cascade to inherited classes in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, enumerable

If I flag a property as `@enumerable(false)` using TypeScript and the method below, the child classes that extend the parent class where this enumerable is flagged to false will have the property but it will be enumerable taking from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40931839/904344).

```
export {}

declare global {
    function enumerable(value: boolean): any;
}

const _global = (global /* node */ || window /* browser */) as any;

/**
 * @enumerable decorator that sets the enumerable property of a class field to false.
 * @param value true|false
 */
_global.enumerable = function(value: boolean): any {
    return function (target: any, propertyKey: string) {
        let descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, propertyKey) || {};
        if (descriptor.enumerable != value) {
            descriptor.configurable = true;
            descriptor.writable = true;
            descriptor.enumerable = value;
            Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, descriptor)
        }
    };
}
```

Here's what my hierarchy looks like:

```
class BaseObject {
    @enumerable(false)
    public _metadata: any = {
        id: 'number',
        name: 'string'
    };
}

class ContainerObject extends BaseObject {
    // ...
}

class CanvasObject extends BaseObject {
    // ...
}
```

And here's what the value of the descriptor is at runtime:

```
var canvas = new CanvasObject();
console.log('Metadata Descriptor: ');
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(canvas, '_metadata'));
Metadata Descriptor:
{ value: 
   { beanId: 'number',
     name: 'string' },
  writable: true,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true }
```

How can I ensure that this property is `enumerable: false` in the parent class and all subsequent inherited classes?

Comment: You have to do it yourself. Inheritance in JavaScript doesn't involve inheriting those flags.

Comment: Every prototype object is its own distinct object, and those object property APIs have nothing specifically to do with prototypes uniquely; they're for all objects.

Comment: Using a prototype chain there is no way you could have gotten the property descriptor using `getOwnPropertyDescriptor` using the child as an argument since that property belongs to the prototype, not the child object. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can I prevent my child classes from inheriting the _metadata object from the parent altogether?

Comment: Sorry @J.Pichardo, I left a typo in the code. I'm getting the property descriptor for `canvas`.

Comment: You are using typescript, which means you can use encapsulation with `private` and `protected` however, that will only make compile-time checks as there are no private variables in javascript.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed that nonetheless if you try to get the object descriptor for `_metadata` from `canvas` you would get `undefined` as `_metadata` is not a property of `canvas` but its prototype.

Comment: With the new `enumerable` method in the answer below, I'm now getting `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that a decorator is applied to class prototype on class declaration. Since `_metadata` is instance property (it's desugared to `constructor() { this._metadata = ... }`), `enumerable` decorator doesn't affect it.

Here is an example of `enumerable` decorator that can be applied to both prototype (usually methods) and instance properties:

```
function enumerable(value: boolean) {
  return (target: any, prop: string, descriptor?: PropertyDescriptor) => {
    if (descriptor) {
      // prototype property
      descriptor.enumerable = value;
    } else {
      // instance property
      let propSymbol = Symbol(prop);

      Object.defineProperty(target, prop, {
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: value,
        get() { return this[propSymbol] },
        set(value) { this[propSymbol] = value }
      });
    }
  };
}
```

Notice that in order to deal with `_metadata = ...` property initializer, descriptor should contain `set` accessor to catch property assignments.

Comment: Alright, I tested this out and I think it's creating the property and correctly making it non-enumerable now, but it isn't setting the value of `_metadata` in the object and returns `undefined` for `dna._metadata`.

Comment: It should work as expected, https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-nam2ew . You can see that _metadata is there and is non-enumerable in Chrome console output (light color).

Comment: How do I prevent TypeScript from desugaring the metadata assignment into the constructor? I have `target: "esnext"` set in my compiler options but it always desugars into a constructor and then the assignment seems to fail.

Comment: I'm not aware what's the exact list covered by esnext target, but I wouldn't expect class fields to be left as is, because they aren't supported natively. 'Syntactic sugar' means that it's functionally identical to desugared counterpart. Whatever the problem is, it shouldn't be caused by that. In the example I've posted class fields are obviously desugared to constructor code on compilation.

Comment: I renamed `_metadata` to `metadata` and changed my target from `esnext` to `es2017` and it's working! Thanks a lot, I needed to get this working before the end of the week.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to share an 'enhancement.'

After implementing Estus answer, I was no longer able to delete the property, though `delete obj.prop` was returning `true`.

When you use `defineProperty`, `writable` defaults to false.

```
export { };

declare global {
  function defineProp(props: { enumerable?: boolean, writable?: boolean, configurable?: boolean }): any;
}

/**
* decorator that sets the enumerable property of a class field to false.
* @param props: object to set {configurable, writable, enumerable}
*/
global.defineProp = function (props) {
  return (target: any, prop: string, descriptor?: PropertyDescriptor) => {
    if (descriptor) {
      // prototype property
      descriptor.configurable = props.configurable;
      descriptor.enumerable = props.enumerable;
      descriptor.writable = props.writable;
    } else {
      // instance property
      let propSymbol = Symbol(prop);

      Object.defineProperty(target, prop, {
        configurable: props.configurable ?? false,
        enumerable: props.enumerable ?? false,
        writable: props.writable ?? false
      });
    }
  };
}
```