# Property descriptor set to enumerable: false, writable: true on class

Tags: typescript, properties, descriptor

I would like to hide somme member to the `for in` loop in javascript/typescript with the descriptor

```
const defaultDescriptor = {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    writable: true
}
```

More pressingly, I would like to apply this descriptor to a member of a class so that every instance of this class would inherits from the descriptor for that member.

I tried this :

```
"use strict";

class Test1 {
    test1 = 1;
}

Object.defineProperty(Object.getPrototypeOf(Test1), "test1", defaultDescriptor);
Object.defineProperty(Test1.constructor, "test1", defaultDescriptor);
Object.defineProperty(Test1, "test1", defaultDescriptor);

const t = new Test1();
console.log(Object.keys(t)); // expected [], received [ "test1" ]
```

[playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%22use%20strict%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20defaultDescriptor%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20configurable%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20enumerable%3A%20false%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20writable%3A%20true%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Test1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test1%20%3D%201%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AObject.defineProperty(Object.getPrototypeOf(Test1)%2C%20%22test1%22%2C%20defaultDescriptor)%3B%0D%0AObject.defineProperty(Test1.constructor%2C%20%22test1%22%2C%20defaultDescriptor)%3B%0D%0AObject.defineProperty(Test1%2C%20%22test1%22%2C%20defaultDescriptor)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20t%20%3D%20new%20Test1()%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(Object.keys(t))%3B%20%2F%2F%20expected%20%5B%5D%2C%20received%20%5B%20%22test1%22%20%5D%0D%0A)

But the property `test1` is still enumerable.

I also tried this

```
"use strict";

function notEnumerable(target: any, propertyKey: string) {
    let descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, propertyKey) || defaultDescriptor;
    descriptor.enumerable = false;
    Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, descriptor)
}

class Test2 {
    @notEnumerable
    test2 = 2
}

const t = new Test2();
console.log(Object.keys(t)); // expected [], received [ "test2" ]
```

[playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%22use%20strict%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20defaultDescriptor%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20configurable%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20enumerable%3A%20false%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20writable%3A%20true%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20notEnumerable(target%3A%20any%2C%20propertyKey%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20descriptor%20%3D%20Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target%2C%20propertyKey)%20%7C%7C%20defaultDescriptor%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20descriptor.enumerable%20%3D%20false%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Object.defineProperty(target%2C%20propertyKey%2C%20descriptor)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Test2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%40notEnumerable%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test2%20%3D%202%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20t%20%3D%20new%20Test2()%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(Object.keys(t))%3B%20%2F%2F%20expected%20%5B%5D%2C%20received%20%5B%20%22test2%22%20%5D%0D%0A)

This second attempt is inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40931839/10519371), but the answer is incorrect for me (an error pop up with the `"use strict"` because writable is false by default).

Note that if I replace `defaultDescriptor` by `{}` then the member `test2` is not enumerable, but it isn't writable either.

Do you know a way to declare a member as writable, and not enumerable at class level (by opposition to instance level, in which case everything works fine) ?